# What is the cost of an endowed chair in a medical school?

Tags: funding

What would be a typical cost for a donor to start up an endowed chair for a professor (an MD) in a medical school?  Are there ongoing costs?

Answer (score 3):

For a fully endowed position, multiply the expected salary, benefits, and research funds by 20x to get an approximation.

If the researcher is making $250,000 in salary and benefits and $250,000 in funding for their lab, then you would want around $10,000,000 endowment minimum (salary and lab numbers chosen for ease of calculation rather than proximity to reality).

This assumes a 5% per annum draw on the endowment, which is both conservative and average. A university with better fund managers could draw 8-10%; a very conservative institution or a place that wants to grow the endowment endogenously might only draw 3-5%.

And as @Dawn notes, for some positions not all position costs are paid entirely out of the endowment, and thus may require a smaller investment. For example, some endowed chairs might only receive 30% of their salary from the named endowment and the rest from general funds. If that were the case in the above example, the endowment would only have to be at the $3 million level.

Answer (score 3):

RoboKaren is right that the annual expected outlay is 5% of the value of the endowed fund. However, many universities allow for endowed chairs that do not cover the full cost of a faculty member's salary and lab. At some universities, the required amount to start a fund is also rank-specific (assistant prof/full prof/dean).

If you have a particular institution in mind, you may be able to find the information on the costs to start and endowed chair on their website. For instance, Duke's policy is here: https://dukeforward.duke.edu/ways-to-give/endowment/endowment-giving/

The amount for an assistant professor at Duke is $1.5M. From my experience with development, this is roughly consistent with other universities.

Ongoing expenses should not be required. However, some universities have policies which allow donors start the chair with have of the amount funded. In this case, the donor would continue to make payments to cover the other half of the amount on some mutually-agreed-upon schedule.